# Disabling Log4J logger on ALL external libraries

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am developing a project with lots of external libraries that most are using Log4J. Currently, we are identifying them and turning their log level to OFF one by one in `log4j.properties`. I was wondering if there is a more efficient solution that one can *turn off logger on **all packages** except **one***?

I researched a lot on StackOverflow, but almost all answers are revolving around explicitly turning off the loggers for external libraries individually, which is not an efficient solution in our case.

For reference, our `log4j.properties` looks like this:

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, stdout

# here we exclude loggers for external packages one by one
log4j.logger.com.github.external1 = OFF
log4j.logger.com.github.external2 = OFF
log4j.logger.org.external3 = OFF
....
log4j.logger.com.example.external100 = OFF

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=./log.out

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log4j organizes it's loggers in a hierarchy. If you turn off the root logging you deactivate all but can still turn on your well known packages, which are a lot less than all the others. Here is an example based on yours:

```
# Define the root logger with appender file and turn all the categories off
log4j.rootLogger = OFF, stdout

# Now turn on only my packages
log4j.logger.com.mycompany = DEBUG

# here we exclude loggers for external packages one by one
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=./log.out

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

However be aware this configuration file works on Log4j 1. You want to migrate to Log4j 2.17.x to mitigate that famous vulnerability.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work for me. I replaced `log4j.logger.com.mycompany = DEBUG` with `log4j.logger.<groupId> = DEBUG` and it does not log anything after I close the root logger. The `groupId` is directly coming from my `pom.xml`. Am I missing anything?

Comment: The line does not contain a group id. It is a category or logger name. Typically programmers use fully qualified class names, so you need to match the package name. The real answer is in the code: Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(????????); log.error("hello world"); Look at the question marks!